# How to show related items with pagination in Eloquent and Blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

AdminsController

```
public function index(){
    $someMessages=$this->blog->paginate(5);
    $users=User::all();
    // return 'Welcome Admin';
    return View::make('admin.admin',['someMessages'=>$someMessages,'users'=>$users]);
}
```

admin.blade.php
Here need to display username from 'users' variable based on uid stored in 'someMessages' object.

```
@extends('layout.default')
@section('title')
    <title>Welcome Admin</title>
@stop

@section('content')
    @foreach($someMessages as $message) 
        <blockquote>{{$message['blog']}}
            <small>
                <cite>

                </cite>
            </small>
        </blockquote>
    @endforeach
{{ $someMessages->links()}}
@stop
```

Comment: Can you show us the `Message` model?

Comment: Try dd(getQueryLog()) and you will come to know what actually you are querying...!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Eloquent relation between blog messages and users defined correctly you don't need to query the users separately. What you want to do is just go with the eager loading:

```
//in case you call it author in your "relation definition"
$someMessages = $this->blog->with('author')->paginate(5);
```

And then in your Blade template:

```
@foreach($someMessages as $message) 
  <div>
    <div>{{ $message->blog }}</div>
    <div>{{ $message->author->name }}</div>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

If you haven't declared the relationship yet - it's easy. Open up your user eloquent model class and add a method:

```
public function blogs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Blog', 'uid');
}
```

In the blog eloquent model class you'd add:

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'uid');
}
```

More about eloquent and relationships can be found [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships).

If that's not the case you can still filter your users collection to get the one you want:

```
@foreach($someMessages as $message)
<?php
  $user = $users->filter(function($user) use ($message)
  {
      return $user->id == $message->uid;
  })->first();
?>
  <div>
    <div>{{ $message->blog }}</div>
    <div>{{ $user->name }}</div>
  </div>
@foreach
```

What happens here is you filter your users collection based on `$message->uid` value and take the first one from it (it should always be just one or none since user IDs are unique).

Although you need to understand that in this case you will get all the users from database and filter through them for every blog message you're outputting. Eager loading is a much better idea here and I'd stick to it if possible.

Comment: I updated the answer. Based on your output you should try $message->users->username, but check the eloquent relationships to define everything correctly

Comment: Yep! I did that. Thanks a lot.